# Плагин Wordprеss для автоматического поста картинок.

Tags: wordpress, плагин

Здравствуйте. Есть папка "images" в нем около 1000 фото. Я хочу автоматически опубликовать каждую в отдельный пост.

Answer (score 3):

[wp_insert_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post)

Собственно - напишите функцию... в которой берёте все картинки из папки и запихиваете в массив... Далее проходитесь по массиву и публикуете данные с помощью функции `wp_insert_post`... Собственно как она работает описано по ссылке...

Answer (score 2):

Если вы с другой платформы, то удобней при помощи [плагина](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-importer/). Можно сформировать по правилам XML и загрузить. Но честно говоря вам проще с базу залить напрямую.